# Importing data from SQL Server to Neo4J

Tags: sql, neo4j

First let me explain. My platform is mostly Windows and my data mostly resides in a relational database (SQL Server 2008). I primarily work with C# but occasuionally work with PERL and JavaScript. I was looking to learning what a graph database could do for my data but there seems to be a continual stream of tools and utilities that are not available that I need to install and learn. I am so busy learning the tools that I loose focus of what I really want and that is to work with a graph database. 
It seems that Neo4j is relatively small and should be accessible to evaluate its features. I would like to import my data from an existing SQL database into Neo4J with the relationships established initially via the foreign keys. The idea seems relatively straightforward but it seems I need to learn Java, PHP, etc. not only to access Neo4J but also to access the existing database. I was wondering if anyone had some recommendations, tools, documentation that would accomplish this goal fairly simply. Do I do down the route of PHP? Java? What additional libraries/packages do I need? What tools are most useful? Thank you.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this. I'm from a .Net background and have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the Neo4J batch importer, [which can be found on github](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import).  Using this, we were able to export 20 million nodes and relationships to import them into Neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to write your own. [Neo4jD](http://sonyarouje.com/2012/02/10/neo4jd-net-client-for-neo4j-graph-database-part-2/) looks interesting.